# Resolving a Video Resource given a YouTube URL

Tags: youtube-api

SoundCloud's API has a [nice endpoint](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#resolving) for submitting a permalink and getting back information about the media there.

Given the many YouTube URL variants (i.e. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-<someID>`, `http://youtu.be/-<someID>`, `http://www.youtube.com/v/-<someID>?version=3&autohide=1`, etc...) is there a way to request a [Video Resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource-representation) given a URL?

Comment: by using the youtube api you can, but not with a direct url

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) which returns a list of videos that match the API request parameters.

**HTTP request:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
```

You can also add query parameters and additional properties in your HTTP request for multiple video resources properties as given in the documentation.

Sample requests to the YouTube API are shown in [Sample API Requests](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests#intro).

Answer (score -1):

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=`*{VIDEO_ID}*`&key=`*{YOUR_API_KEY}*